# angularjs display select input when another input is selected otherwise default value

Tags: angularjs

I have this in my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Order type</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="orderType" ng-model="controller.orderLine.orderType" ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in controller.orderTypes" required></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-if="controller.orderLine.orderType === 2">
    <label class="control-label">Unit of measure</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="unitOfMeasure" ng-model="controller.orderLine.unitOfMeasure" ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in controller.unitOfMeasures" required></select>
</div>
```

As you can see, if the **orderType** is set to 2, then it will show the **unitOfMeasure** select input. 
What I would like, is when a user changes the **orderType** to 2, it shows the **unitOfMeasure** select input, but if they change it to something else, I would like **controller.orderLine.unitOfMeasure** to be set to 0.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add ng-change to first select `ng-change="onchange()"`
In controller:

```
$scope.onchange = function() {
    if ($scope.controller.orderLine.orderType != 2) {
        $scope.controller.orderLine.unitOfMeasure = 0;
    }
}
```